# Can pregnant dwellers in Fallout Shelter dance?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I got an objective to have 15 male and female couples dance. I'm at 9 times now and I've only 2 pregnant women (I only need 2 right now, might ruin it if I get another one).

My question is: if I put a pregnant dweller with a male dweller in the living quarters, will they still dance?

Comment: Such a missed opportunity to name the question `Can pregnant people dance`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Dwellers dance when they are about to make a baby.**

Given that pregnant dwellers can not get pregnant, **no. Pregnant dwellers will not dance.**

I have confirmed this with a [GameFAQs forum post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168521-fallout-shelter/72215671), where a user advises on how to complete this objective quickly, and without the issue of having to worry about overpopulation.

**TL, DR**: As soon as the dwellers start dancing, it counts as them having danced. Immediately move one of the dwellers to a different room, then immediately move them back. The "baby making process" will reset, and you will have made them dance, without getting one of them pregnant.

Answer (score 1):

No. When your dwellers dance it means that they are preparing to have a baby. And some advice to you: Don't get too many dwellers pregnant, because they won't fight if there is an attack.

Comment: it's true they won't fight back if there's an attack, but you can use that as your strategy too, children and pregnant female dwellers /can't/ die